# Compute $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n $, with $a_{n} = \frac{n^6+n+7*4^{n+1}}{4^n-16}$

Tags: limits

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$, with $a_n = \frac{n^6+n+7*4^{n+1}}{4^n-16}$

Wolfram says that the result of this is 28. How do I get that result? I'm clueless as to where to begin, I know you're supposed to change some of these to $\frac{n^6}{n}$, because that equals $0$.

I tried dividing top and bottom by $4^n$, but I'm not sure what is for example: $\frac{16}{4^n}$ is that $\frac{16}{4^n} =0$?

Comment: First, divide top and bottom by $4^n$.

Comment: Ok I did, but is $\frac{16}{4^n} = 0$?

Comment: On the Wolfram Alpha app you can hit "show steps" and it will show you how.

Comment: $\frac{16}{4^n} \neq 0$ for any $n \in \mathbb{R}$. But $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{16}{4^n} = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } a_{n}  = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{\frac{n^6}{4^n}+\frac{n}{4^n}+7\cdot 4}{1-\frac{16}{4^n}} = 28.$$

Comment: How did you get $7*4$ from $\frac{7*4^{n+1}}{4^n}$? Shouldn't that be $7*4^{n}$?

Comment: no, you should subtract the powers (n+1)-n

Comment: $\frac{7 \cdot 4^{n+1}}{4^n} = \frac{7 \cdot 4 \cdot 4^{n}}{4^n} = 7\cdot 4 = 28$

Comment: I have answered your question! If you have problems with limits, there are many books that explain it.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I understand now :)